# Angular Universal requires initialNavigation=enabled which breaks APP_INITIALIZER and Guards

Tags: angular, angular-universal

While adding Angular Universal to our app, we had to set the `initialNavigation="enabled"` flag on the router, in order to avoid flickering.

Now this comes with 2 issues for us:

1. we create routes dynamically, opening one of those routes now fails
2. because the app does not wait for the `APP_INITIALIZER`s to load, routes that are guarded cannot be loaded, because the guard always assumes the user is unauthorized, because the check is happening in the `APP_INITIALIZER`

I found several Github issues about this (i.e. https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1623) but none of them really provided a solution.

How can I use `initialNavigation="enabled"` while at the same time wait for the `APP_INITIALIZER`s to be executed?

**edit (01/02/2021)**: in Angular 11 the wording has changed and the option is now called `enabledBlocking`. The issue mentioned here however is not touched by this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I did hack something together, yes: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1817#issuecomment-699898024

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, will have a look at it!

Comment: I advanced a lot but I'm stuck on DYNAMIC_ROUTES injector token. Is that a service or how does it look like? Much appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: No that is just an InjectionToken: `export const DYNAMIC_ROUTES = new InjectionToken<IEnvironment>('dynamicRoutes');`

Comment: AND it just works! You're amazing! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide the solution I found here as well. I also posted it as an [issue](http://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1817#issuecomment-699898024) at Angular Universal's Github repository. If there are changes made to Universal, which will make this easier, I will update this answer.

**Solution**:
Basically what I do now, is to fetch the data about the pages, both in the server and the app, before the Angular app gets bootstrapped at all. Altering the `routes`-array within `app-routing.modules`-constructor apparently is early enough to get the dynamic routes in, before the router does its initial navigation.

It looks more or less like this (as stated by Nicolae this can be refactored to avoid the duplicate code):

`server.ts`:

```js
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  // fetch dynamic routes
  // /!\ duplicate code to src/main.ts
  fetch('http://static.content/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(resp => {
      const routes = resp.entries.map(route => ({
        path: route.path,
        component: StaticContentComponent,
        data: {
          id: route._id,
          name: route.name
        }
      }));

      res.render(indexHtml, {
        req,
        providers: [
          { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
          { provide: DYNAMIC_ROUTES, useValue: routes }
        ]
      });
    });
  });

  return server;
}
```

and basically the same in `main.ts`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // fetch dynamic routes
  // /!\ duplicate code to server.ts
  fetch('http://static.content/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(resp => {
      const routes = resp.entries.map(route => ({
        path: route.path,
        component: StaticContentComponent,
        data: {
          id: route._id,
          name: route.name
        }
      }));

      platformBrowserDynamic([
        { provide: DYNAMIC_ROUTES, useValue: routes }
      ])
        .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
});
```

And then in my `app-routing.module.ts` I add the data provided in `DYNAMIC_ROUTES` to the routes:

```js
const DYNAMIC_ROUTES = new InjectionToken<IEnvironment>('dynamicRoutes');

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabled'
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  constructor(@Inject(DYNAMIC_ROUTES) private dynamicRoutes, private router: Router) {
    const config = router.config;
    config.unshift(...this.dynamicRoutes);
    this.router.resetConfig(config);
  }
}
```

Comment: okay, hmm, that's an overkill, isn't it? couldn't you just "next" an observable on "App_Initializer" then watched it until it has some value in the guard? does that work?

Answer (score 1):

1. 'enabledBlocking' - The initial navigation starts before the root
   component is created. The bootstrap is blocked until the initial
   navigation is complete. This value is required for server-side
   rendering to work.
2. 'enabledNonBlocking' - (default) The initial navigation starts after
   the  root component has been created. The bootstrap is not blocked
   on the completion of the initial

i hope this help

> ```
>  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
>       relativeLinkResolution: 'corrected',
>       initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
>       useHash: true
>     }),
> ```

Comment: This is a change introduced by Angular v11, it does however just clean up the wording / removes legacy options and does not help with the issue described in the question. `enabledBlocking` is a one-to-one replacement for `enabled` (https://angular.io/api/router/InitialNavigation)